# Is "xargs" on MacOS not the same as linux?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, xargs

For the following command:

`docker ps -a -q | xargs -r docker kill`

I get this error:

`xargs: illegal option -- r`

What would be the MacOS equivalent of the above command?

Comment: One ghetto ass solution I just found is using `-n5000` which on Mac sets the maximum number of arguments. It seems to work, but not an elegant solution. Wondering if there's a cleaner way.

Comment: `-n5000` is the default on Mac xargs. I don't think specifying it explicitly has any effect.

Comment: GNU coreutils is different from BSD coreutils.

Comment: If you are still confused, Linux has GNU (GNU's Not Unix) utilities bundled, MacOS uses BSD (Berkeley Software Distribution).  There are many differences.

Answer (score 12):

The equivalent is simply `docker ps -a -q | xargs docker kill`.

`-r` (aka. `--no-run-if-empty`) is only necessary on GNU xargs because it will always run the command at least once by default, even if there is no input; `-r` disables this. BSD xargs does not have this behavior, so there's no need to disable it.